# Member function of nested class returns type of nested class

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested-class

I have a struct within a class like this

```
template <class T>
class a {
    struct b {
        int var;
        b *foo(const T&);
    };
    int var;
};
```

and I want to define `foo` outside of `struct b`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <class T>
typename a<T>::b* a<T>::b::foo(const T&)
{
    //code
}
```